# Cannot Import Python packages

Tags: python-3.x

[image: This first picture is my structure of my project]

[image: The second picture is error message]

I'm working in app.py amd I want to import a method called auto_email in email_svr.py, but it throws me with an error saying cannot import.

Comment: do you want to import a method called auto_email ior send_email ? check if the function is actually in the file?

Comment: function is actually in the file and i want to import send_email.